# Compare items from lists and find similarity

Tags: python, similarity, fuzzywuzzy

I would like to compare items from two lists (please see below). I am looking for similarity about the items. For example, I have this item from `b_list`:

```
http://www.ilcorrieredellanotte.it
```

which is similar to `Corriere della Sera` from `g_list`. An expected output would be:

```
(ilcorrieredellanotte, corrieredellasera) = (score of similarity)
```

Also: `https://www.ilmattoquotidiano.it, http://www.ilfattoquotidaino.it`, and `https://ilquotidaino.wordpress.com` from `b_list` are similar to `il fatto quotidiano` from `g_list`. An example of output would be:

`(ilmattoquotidiano, ilfattoquotidiano) = 90` (they should differ only for `'c'`)
`(ilfattoquotidaino, ilfattoquotidiano) = 95` (they differ only for a vowel, that is switched with another)

`(ilquotidaino, ilfattoquotidiano) =60` (it is missing '`fatto`')

(scores 90, 95, 60 are just used as an example)

I was thinking of using

```
Ratios = [process.extract(x,g_list) for x in b_list]
result = list()
for ratio in Ratios:
    for match in ratio:
        if match[1] !=100:
            result.append(match)
            break
```

but the output has giving me something different (for example, it is not included `"Il fatto quotidiano"` from the list). I think it is because I am comparing list of urls with words separated by spaces and also case sensitive. 
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Lists:

```
b_list =["http://notiziepericolose.blogspot.com","http://www.ilcorrieredellanotte.it","https://www.ilmattoquotidiano.it","http://ioco.altervista.org/blog/","http://www.ilmessaggio.it","http://www.ilcorriere.cloud","http://www.ilfattoquotidaino.it","https://ilquotidaino.wordpress.com","http://www.liberogiornale.com", ]
b_list=[re.sub(r"https?://(www\.)?", r'', a) for a in black_list]

g_list=["Corriere della Sera","la Repubblica","La Gazzetta dello Sport","Corriere dello Sport-Stadio","Italia Oggi","il Giornale","Tuttosport","il Fatto Quotidiano","Il Mattino","Libero","Leggo"]
g_list =[x.lower() for x in g_list]
```

Comment: Take a look at [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple difflib example. It's easy to adjust the cutoff parameter for more or less sensitivity as needed.

```
import difflib

b_list =["http://notiziepericolose.blogspot.com",
         "http://www.ilcorrieredellanotte.it",
         "https://www.ilmattoquotidiano.it",
         "http://ioco.altervista.org/blog/",
         "http://www.ilmessaggio.it",
         "http://www.ilcorriere.cloud",
         "http://www.ilfattoquotidaino.it",
         "https://ilquotidaino.wordpress.com",
         "http://www.liberogiornale.com", ]

g_list=["Corriere della Sera",
        "la Repubblica",
        "La Gazzetta dello Sport",
        "Corriere dello Sport-Stadio",
        "Italia Oggi",
        "il Giornale",
        "Tuttosport",
        "il Fatto Quotidiano",
        "Il Mattino",
        "Libero",
        "Leggo"]

save_dict = {}
save_list = []

for g in g_list:
    matches_list = difflib.get_close_matches(g, possibilities=b_list, cutoff=0.35)
    print(g, (matches_list))

    if len(matches_list) > 0:
        save_dict[g] = matches_list
        save_list.append([g, matches_list])

print(save_dict)

{'Corriere della Sera': ['http://www.ilcorrieredellanotte.it'],
 'Corriere dello Sport-Stadio': ['http://www.ilcorrieredellanotte.it',
  'http://www.ilcorriere.cloud'],
 'il Giornale': ['http://www.liberogiornale.com'],
 'il Fatto Quotidiano': ['https://www.ilmattoquotidiano.it',
  'http://www.ilfattoquotidaino.it',
  'https://ilquotidaino.wordpress.com']}

print(save_list)

[['Corriere della Sera', ['http://www.ilcorrieredellanotte.it']],
 ['Corriere dello Sport-Stadio',
  ['http://www.ilcorrieredellanotte.it', 'http://www.ilcorriere.cloud']],
 ['il Giornale', ['http://www.liberogiornale.com']],
 ['il Fatto Quotidiano',
  ['https://www.ilmattoquotidiano.it',
   'http://www.ilfattoquotidaino.it',
   'https://ilquotidaino.wordpress.com']]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Matthew Borish. May I ask you how I could save in a list only the items that have a value not null?

Comment: Sure, I added save_dict and save_list if you want to store your items.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Matthew. Really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for the [`Levenshtein`](https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity#levenshtein) algorithm, i.e.:

```
from similarity.levenshtein import Levenshtein

levenshtein = Levenshtein()
print(levenshtein.distance('corrieredellasera', 'ilcorrieredellanotte'))
# 7
```

Or, if your prefer to use a different string similarity algorithm, [`JaroWinkler`](https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity/blob/master/README.md#jaro-winkler):

```
from similarity.jarowinkler import JaroWinkler

jarowinkler = JaroWinkler()
print(jarowinkler.similarity('corrieredellasera', 'ilcorrieredellanotte'))
# 0.7221288515406162
```

Notes:

- Install as usual with `pip install strsim`
- [`strsim`](https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity/blob/master/README.md) contains [many other string similarity algorithms](https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity#overview)
- Full documentation is available [here](https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank you @Pedro Lobito. But how can I iterate for all the items in the lists? The problem is that the first list has urls (but it is difficult to apply url parse as it is not an url but a list of strings) and the second has already the netloc extracted.

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm not sure If I fully understand  which type of output you are looking for. Can you update the question with a sample of the desired output?

Comment: Yes, I already updated the question with a sample of desired output.